# Subset of Char Array in C program

Tags: c, arrays

I have written a C- program to reverse the subset of strings. And I am not able to get the output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
{
    int i,j,n,k, size; 
    char a[10]="aabbcc";
    i=0;
    n=strlen(a);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {

        for(j=i;j<n;j++)
        {
            for(k=i;k<j+1;k++)
            {
                printf("%c",a[k]);
                size = strlen(a);
                reverse(a[k], 0, size - 1);
                printf("The string after reversing is: %s\n", a);
            } 
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    getch();
}

void reverse(char str1[], int index, int size)
{
    char temp;
    temp = str1[index];
    str1[index] = str1[size - index];
    str1[size - index] = temp;
    if (index == size / 2)
    {
        return;
    }
    reverse(str1, index + 1, size);
}
```

Suppose my Input is "aabbcc". My substrings will be a, aa, aabb,....etc.
But the the reversing of the string is happening only for my inout word "aabbcc". How do I get the code to reverse all the substrings of the given string.

Comment: This shouldn't even compile without warning. The first argument to `reverse()` is supposed to be an array, but `reverse(a[k], 0, size-1)` passes a single `char` as the first argument.

Comment: If you want to work on a substring, you need to copy it to a temporary array. Otherwise, you're modifying the original string, and future loops won't be be able to get back the original.

Comment: yes!! But how do I pass current substring to reverse it. What changes should I make it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, This code will not compile because of syntax error(s) as Barmar mentioned.

Second, If you only want to print all substring and there reverse this should be easy task

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j,n,k, size; 
    char a[10]="aabbcc";
    i=0;
    n=strlen(a);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {

        for(j=i;j<n;j++)
        {
            printf("substring=");
            for(k=i;k<j+1;k++)
            {
                printf("%c",a[k]);
            } 
            printf("\n");
            printf("reverse=");

            // only reverse the loop!
            for(k=j; k>=i;k--)
            {
                printf("%c",a[k]);
            } 
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

otherwise you need to store the substring in a buffer and send it to your reverse function, because you are modifying the orignal string **a**.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void reverse(char str[], int index, int size); // you need to declare you function first

int main() {
    int i,j,n,k, size; 
    char a[10]="aabbcc";
    i=0;
    n=strlen(a);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=i;j<n;j++)
        {
            char buffer[10];
            int buffer_index = 0;
            for(k=i;k<j+1;k++) {
                buffer[buffer_index++] = a[k];
            }
            buffer[buffer_index] = 0; // add buffer terminating
            printf("current substring=%s\n", buffer);

            // reversing current substring
            size = strlen(buffer);
            reverse(buffer, 0, size - 1); // passing copy of substring instead of a
            printf("The string after reversing is: %s\n", buffer);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}

void reverse(char str[], int index, int size) {
    char temp;
    temp = str[index];
    str[index] = str[size - index];
    str[size - index] = temp;
    if (index == size / 2)
    {
        return;
    }
    reverse(str, index + 1, size);
}
```